# How to show the progress while uploading a file in Asp.net MVC web application, c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my asp.net web application I have a section to upload files, which is working fine but the problem is that the users can't see the progress and it is particularly very necessary while they want to upload larger files.

So my question is that: how can i show the progress (A simple progress bar or the percentage) while uploading a file.
I tried some of the solutions in this forum but none of them worked for me.

Here is the controller:

```
 public ActionResult BriefDetails(int? ID)
    {
       var dtl = _context.Original.SingleOrDefault(b => b.Id == Id);
        var vm = new BriefUploadVM()

        {
            Id = dtl.Id,
            brief_rp = dtl.brief_rp,
        };
        return View(vm);
    }
```

This is the View Model:

```
 public class BriefUploadVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BriefReport { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Error: Attach your file")]
    [NotMapped]
    public HttpPostedFileBase brief_rp { get; set; }
}
```

This is the View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Store", "Reports", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

<div class="form-group">

    <input type="file" name="brief_rp" />
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a=> a.brief_rp)
</div>

@Html.AntiForgeryToken();
@Html.HiddenFor(a => a.Id);
<button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

}

And this is the Store Method inside the controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Store(BriefUploadVM rp)
    {



            string Second_filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(rp.brief_rp.FileName);
            string Second_extension = Path.GetExtension(rp.brief_rp.FileName);
            Second_filename = Second_filename + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + Second_extension;
            rp.BriefReport = "Files/" + Second_filename;
            Second_filename = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Files/"), Second_filename);
            rp.brief_rp.SaveAs(Second_filename);


            var item = _context.original.Single(a => a.Id == rp.Id);
            item.Brief_Report = rp.BriefReport;
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Success", "Project");



    }
```

Comment: "I tried some of the solutions in this forum but none of them worked for me." Why not? What are your specific requirements that differentiate this question from the others?

Comment: "...but none of them worked for me..." - this information is not really helpful. It does not say what exactly did not work, i.e. did you get any error messages anywhere, did you try to debug the issue to make sure that it actually does the intended thing.

Comment: those were not for web application @JohnB

Comment: The answer would not be easy to come up with. You could try something like this https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/85790/uploading-a-file-asynchronously or this https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/uploading-files-asynchronously-using-asp.net-web-api.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the jQuery Form plugin: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload for your requirement.

Here is a sample. You can refer. Hope to help, my friend :))

---Controller---

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult AsynFileUpload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
        {
            int count = 0;
            if (files != null)
            {
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                    {                        
                        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles"), file.FileName);
                        file.SaveAs(path);
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            return new JsonResult
            {
                Data = "Successfully " + count + " file(s) uploaded"
            };
        }
```

---View----

```
<style>
    .progress {
        position: relative;
        width: 400px;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        padding: 1px;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }

    .bar {
        background-color: #B4F5B4;
        width: 0%;
        height: 20px;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }

    .percent {
        position: absolute;
        display: inline-block;
        top: 3px;
        left: 48%;
    }
</style>

<h2> AsynFileUpload </h2>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AsynFileUpload", "Home", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "post" }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input type="file" name="files" multiple />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="upload file" />    
}
<br />
<div class="progress">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <br />
    <div class="percent">0%</div>
</div>
<div id="status"></div>

@section scripts {
    <script src="https://malsup.github.io/min/jquery.form.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function () {

            var bar = $('.bar');
            var percent = $('.percent');
            var status = $('#status');

            $('form').ajaxForm({
                beforeSend: function () {
                    status.empty();
                    var percentVal = '0%';
                    bar.width(percentVal)
                    percent.html(percentVal);
                },
                uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                    var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
                    bar.width(percentVal)
                    percent.html(percentVal);
                },
                success: function () {
                    var percentVal = '100%';
                    bar.width(percentVal)
                    percent.html(percentVal);
                },
                complete: function (xhr) {
                    status.html(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });

        })();
    </script>
}
```

---

Also, the default upload file size if 4MB. To increase it, please use this below section in your web.config -

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```